# Has there been any work done on extensions of "norms" to complex/hypercomplex spaces?

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, normed-spaces, hypercomplex-numbers

Let $x \in \Bbb R^d$ or some other vector space.

Define $\|.\|_c$ as $(\sum_{j=1}^dx_j^c)^{\frac{1}{c}}$ where $c \in \Bbb C$ (Complex number) or $\Bbb H$ (other hypercomplex number systems).

I was playing around with this idea and wondered if anyone knew of any work that has been done on this.

Comment: $z^\alpha$ is not well-defined in general if $z$ is a complex number or even a negative real number, even if $\alpha$ is real, so your definition does not really make sense as it is.

Comment: As @GreginGre already mentioned with complex numbers you have to be careful about branches and in that case, your norm is a complex, multi-valued function. Even when $c$ is real and $0<c<1$ this does not defines a norm is the usual sense. [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#When_0_%3C_p_%3C_1)

Comment: Modulus usually is $\sqrt[n]{\det A}$ where $A$ is the matrix form of the n-dimensional hypercomplex number.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a modulus of (hyper)complex numbers is defined as follows:

$|z|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^N a_k i_k\right|=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^N s_k a_k^2}$

where $s_k$ are the components of the metric signature of the space, and depending on the exact hypercomplex number system, can be either $0$, $1$ or $-1$. This modulus is not, generally, a norm, it is a norm only if all $s_k=1$.

Since this expression can be imaginary (but not negative), and the system in question may not include imaginary numbers (such as split-complex numbers), some authors use the square of the above expression and call it "modulus", so to avoid use of imaginary numbers.